# How to display array in matrix table of php

Tags: php, for-loop, html-table

I have two arrays:

```
$token = array('technology', 'languange', 'town', 'gadget', 'smartphone');

$num = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25);
```

How to display that array into the table using :

> ==========================================
>
> |----Token-----| num1 | num2 | num3 | num4 | num5 |
>
> |-Technology-|---1----|---2----|---3----|---4----|---5----|
>
> |--Language--|---6----|---7----|---8----|---9----|---10----|
>
> |-----Town-----|---11---|---12---|---13---|---14---|---15---|
>
> |----Gadget----|---16----|---17---|---18---|---19---|---20---|
>
> |-Smartphone-|---21---|---22---|---23---|---24---|---25---|
>
> ==========================================

This is my code:

```
...
$counttoken = count($token);
foreach($token as $key=>$value)
        {
            echo "<tr><td>$value</td>";
            for($i=0; $i<$counttoken;$i++)
            {
                echo "<td>" .$num[$i]. "</td>";
            }
        }
...
```

But, the result is:

> ==========================================
>
> |----Token-----| num1 | num2 | num3 | num4 | num5 |
>
> |-Technology-|---1----|---2----|---3----|---4----|---5----|
>
> |--Language--|---1----|---2----|---3----|---4----|---5----|
>
> |-----Town-----|---1----|---2----|---3----|---4----|---5----|
>
> |----Gadget----|---1----|---2----|---3----|---4----|---5----|
>
> |-Smartphone-|---1----|---2----|---3----|---4----|---5----|
>
> ==========================================

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$counttoken = count($token);
$k=0;
foreach($token as $key=>$value)
    {
        echo "<tr><td>$value</td>";
        for($i=0; $i<$counttoken;$i++)
        {
            echo "<td>" .$num[$k++]. "</td>";
        }
    }
```

Comment: @DharmeshPatel +1 for simple & bang on target answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it is working. I checked this as per your requirement.

```
<?php
$token = array('technology', 'languange', 'town', 'gadget', 'smartphone');

$num = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25);

$counttoken = count($token);
echo "<table>";
foreach($token as $key=>$value)
{
    echo "<tr><td>$value</td>";
    for($i=0; $i<$counttoken;$i++)
    {
        echo "<td>" .$num[$i + ($key * $counttoken)]. "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try this   

    $counttoken = count($token);

    foreach($token as $key=>$value)
            {  
                echo "<tr><td>$value</td>";
                for($i=0; $i<$counttoken;$i++)
                {
                    echo "<td>" .$num[$i]. "</td>";
                }
                $num = array_slice($num,$counttoken); 

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is code, that can help you

```
$counttoken = count($token);
$cnt = 0;
foreach($token as $key=>$value)
        {
            echo "<tr><td>$value</td>";
            for($i=0; $i<$counttoken;$i++)
            {
                if(isset($num[($i+$cnt)]))
                {
                    echo "<td>" .$num[($i+$cnt)]. "</td>";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
                }

            }
            $cnt=$cnt+$counttoken;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for the `$num` array... another possible solution, which will automatically adjust as you add more tokens to the `$token` array...

```
<? $token = array('technology', 'languange', 'town', 'gadget', 'smartphone'); ?>
<? $tc = count($token); ?>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Token</th>
                <? for($j=1;$j<=$tc;$j++):?>
                    <th>num<?= $j;?></th>
                <? endfor;?>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <? foreach($token as $tK => $tV):?>
            <tr>
                <td><?= $tV?></td>
                <? for($i = ($tK*$tc + 1); $i <= ($tK*$tc + $tc) ; $i++):?>
                    <td><?= $i;?></td>
                <? endfor;?>
            </tr>
            <? endforeach;?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Sorry for share only code. see below the code explanation.

We have two arrays, token and num our output should be

technology 1 2 3 4 5  \n 
languange  6 7 8 9 10  \n
town       11 12 13 14 15

SO see my comment in code

```
       <?php
        $token = array('Technology', 'languange', 'town', 'gadget', 'smartphone');
        $num = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25);
        $counttoken = count($token);
        $k = 0;
        foreach($token as $value)
        {
            echo "<tr><td>".$value."</td>"; // here i am just printing the token value like 'Technology'
            for($i=0; $i<$counttoken;$i++)
            {
                if(isset($num[$i+$k]))
                {
                    echo "<td>" .$num[$i+$k]. "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>";// for first loop of token it will print value of $num[0] to $num[4] means 1,2,3,4,5 and for second loop of token it will print $num[5+0] to $num [5+4] means 6,7,8,9,10 etc
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
                }
            }
            $k=$k+$counttoken;     // increase the value of $k for spliting $num array in 5 interval
            echo "</tr><br>"; // for new line
        }       
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function matrics($int){
$j = $int*$int;
for($i=1;$i<=$j;$i++){
    echo $i.' ';
        if($i%$int==0)
        echo '<br/>';
}
}

matrics(4);

?>
```